# How to make a second div fill the remaining height of the screen without scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs: the first has 100px height, and the second I want to fill the remaining of the screen without having vertical scrollbars. I tried to set the second divs height to 100%, but the scrollbar appeared.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="wihe100">
        <div class="firstDiv">
            AAA
        </div>
        <div class="wihe100 redBack">
            BBB
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

html, body 
{ 
    height:100%; 
    margin: 0px;
}

.wihe100
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.redBack
{
    background-color: #FF0000;
}

.firstDiv
{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #0000FF;
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wHtX7/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option1: Give red background to body itself.

```
html, body{
    height:100%; 
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
.firstDiv{

    height: 100px;
    background-color: #0000FF;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/wHtX7/2/)

Option 2: Set height of `redBack` 100% - 100px.

HTML:

```
<div class="wihe100">
    <div class="firstDiv">AAA</div>
    <div class="redBack">BBB</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {    
    margin: 0px;
}
html, body,.wihe100 {
    height:100%;
}
.redBack {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    height:calc(100% - 100px);
}
.firstDiv {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #0000FF;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/wHtX7/10/)

Comment: Option 2 does not work in IE8 (put in separate file outside fiddle is it neither work in IE8). Although there was no requirement for IE8.

Comment: @koral yes `calc` doesnt work in IE. You can use option 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `overflow: hidden;` on the parent DIV `<div class="wihe100">` that contains both your DIVs.

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wHtX7/9/)

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't notice, I will fix my answer

Comment: The problem with this is that if the second div has a lot of content, then the content that does not fit on the screen does not get displayed. http://jsfiddle.net/wHtX7/12/

Comment: If there is more content than fits on screen, either some content is not displayed or there is a scroll bar. He said "I want to fill the remaining of the screen without having vertical scrollbars" therefore not-showing-all-content is the only logical solution.

Comment: @Daew: I want the scrollbar to appear only when the content in the second div does not fit anymore on the screen

Comment: This could probably be solved with overflow and min-height, I will try to post a solution a couple of hours if noone does that before

Answer (score 1):

Use flexbox

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="wihe100">
            <div class="firstDiv">
                AAA
            </div>
            <div class="wihe100 redBack">
                BBB
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

-

```
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wihe100 {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.firstDiv {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
}

.redBack {
    background-color: blue;
    flex: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wHtX7/16/

Comment: You'll need to add vendor prefixes for some browsers

Answer (score 0):

I think by adding

```
overflow-y:hidden;
```

to your .wihe100 class will help.

Comment: The problem with this is that if the second div has a lot of content, then the content that does not fit on the screen does not get displayed. http://jsfiddle.net/wHtX7/12/

Comment: ok I got it, what about this? does it works for you? adding height auto and relative position in your parent div and height auto in the red div. http://jsfiddle.net/wHtX7/15/

Comment: A scroolbar appeared on Chrome and IE